# typescript declare third party modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, declare

How could I declare a third party module which looks like this:

in third party module:

```
module.exports = function foo(){
  // do somthing
}
```

in my code:

```
import * as foo from 'foo-module'; // Can not find a declaration module for ...
foo();
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Check out the [documentation on working with 3rd party modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries).

How to write the declaration depends a lot on how the module was written and what it exports.

The example you've given is a CommonJS module (`module.exports = ...`) which is not really a valid ES6 module, because ES6 cannot export a function *as the module* (it can only export function members or a *default* function).

## Update for TypeScript 2.7+

With the added [`esModuleInterop` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-from-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop) you no longer need to use the "namespace hack" shown below for CommonJS modules that have a non-ES6 compatible export.

First, make sure you've enabled `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json` (which is now included by default with `tsc --init`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions" {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
   }
}
```

Declare your `foo-example` in a `.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare module "foo-module" {
  function foo(): void; 
  export = foo;
}
```

Now you can import it as a namespace like you wanted:

```
import * as foo from "foo-module";
foo();
```

Or as a default import:

```
import foo from "foo-module";
foo();
```

## Older workaround

You can declare your `foo-example` in a `.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare module "foo-module" {
  function foo(): void; 
  namespace foo { } // This is a hack to allow ES6 wildcard imports
  export = foo;
}
```

And import like you wanted:

```
import * as foo from "foo-module";
foo();
```

Or like this:

```
import foo = require("foo-module");
foo();
```

---

The [documentation has a good resource on declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) and some [templates for various kinds of declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates.html).

Comment: What happens if `foo()` is already called inside the module and the result is what's exported? How do you type that?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. And struggled to add a type definition to my project. Finally, I was able to achieve it using the following steps.

This is some module (just with constants), lets call it `some-module` - node_modules/some-module/index.js.

```
'use strict';

exports.__esModule = true;
var APPS = exports.APPS = {
    ona: 'ona',
    tacq: 'tacq',
    inetAcq: 'inetAcq'
};
```

First I add to tsconfig.json `baseUrl` and `typeRoots`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "types",
    "typeRoots": ["types"]
  }
  ...
}
```

Second in my project root I create folder `types` with same folders structure for the module `types/some-module/index.js` and place the code:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
    type Apps =  {
        ona: string;
        tacq: string;
        inetAcq: string;
    };
    let APPS: Apps
}
```

Finally I can import it in my `my-file.ts` with typings!

```
import { APPS } from 'some-module';
```