# How to import third party module in node.js with typescript, if there @types is not available?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I want to import `sails-redis`, `modelling`, `clean-obj` and other 3rd party modules in Node, but I'm using typescript. so it is showing me an error:
**Can not find a declaration module for clean-obj**

I'm doing this:

```
import * as cleanObj from 'clean-obj';
```

It is not working, showing an error.
But if do as below it works, but I don't think is it a proper way in typescript or not.

```
const cleanObj-obj = require('clean-obj');
```

I want to import 3rd party module which does not have typings in npm. 
Kindly suggest me a proper way to add typings for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript declare third party modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058101/typescript-declare-third-party-modules)

Comment: That question is exporting own created module foo, not a third party module. And in its answer, he is recommending module which has typings, but my case it does not have typings.
But I want to import 3rd party module which does not have typings in npm.