# Error: Could not find declaration file for module VueJS application

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, typescript-typings

Hi I am using NuxtJS to build a VueJS application. I have installed an image cropping library [vue-croppie](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-croppie). I have imported the Vue component as per the documentation  like below

```
import VueCroppie from 'vue-croppie'
```

However, I am getting the following error on import statement

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-croppie'. 'xxx/node_modules/vue-croppie/dist/vue-croppie.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-croppie` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-croppie';

I have tried declaring `index.d.ts` file at the root of my project with following content but id doesn't solve the problem

```
declare module 'vue-croppie';
```

I have tried using `require` like below as suggested on other posts but of no use

```
const VueCroppie = require('vue-croppie')
```

I understand this is a Typescript issue but have no knowledge about Typescript. Can somebody throw more light on this. What is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Used library simply doesn't provide type hints. You can use it untyped or declare type info yourself. Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44058101/typescript-declare-third-party-modules

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had not installed the plugin with VueJS app. Here is how to do it.

**VueJS**

We can use [Vue.use](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use) to isntall a plugin before it can be used like below

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCroppie from 'vue-croppie';

Vue.use(VueCroppie)
```

**NuxtJS**

In case of NuxtJS it is little different. The plugin is registered globally, here's how.

1. Create a file called `vue-croppie.js` under plugin folder. And add the following to it

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import VueCroppie from 'vue-croppie'

   Vue.use(VueCroppie)
   ```
2. In your `nuxt.config.js` add this under plugins

```
{ src: '~/plugins/vue-croppie.js', ssr: false }
```

Now, the plugin will be available globally. So there is no need to import and can be used directly.