# Declaration files in Javascript library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have my own JS library and I add there declaration files (`*.d.ts`) for my TS projects which use that JS library. There's something wrong and my TS project ignore that declaration files.

---

So I tried this stupid example in my TS project.

```
// project/src/calculateSum.js

function calculateSum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

module.exports = {
  calculateSum
}
```

```
// project/src/types/custom/calculateSum.d.ts

export declare function calculateSum(a: number, b: number): number;
```

```
// project/src/app.ts

import { calculateSum } from './calculateSum`

console.log(calculateSum('it should not acceept string', 1))
```

VS code and TS does not report anny issue with that.

Here my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "src/types/custom"
      ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
  ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

BTW I have also `svg.d.ts` inside `src/types/custom` and it works as expected.

```
// project/src/types/custom/svg.d.ts
declare module "*.svg" {
    import React = require("react")
    export const AsComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>
    const src: string
    export default src
}
```

It seems to me that I misunderstood something.

Comment: You need to declare a module inside which you export without `declare`, see this please:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Comment: IIRC `typeRoots` is for packages, i.e. `import … from 'calculateSum'`. But when you `import … from './calculateSum'`, then the declarations for that particular module would be expected to be found in `./calculateSum.d.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the type definitions for your `.js` files should be in the same folder for it to work, since you can have multiple definition files with the same function declared in each.

Your `svg.d.ts` works as expected, probably because that's a general definition for all `*.svg` imports (I think).

Also, check this answer on a similar topic out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060120/15076557

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by adding in your tsconfig.json :

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "rootDirs": ["src", "src/types/custom"],
  ...
}
```

[TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs)

> Using rootDirs, you can inform the compiler that there are many “virtual” directories acting as a single root. This allows the compiler to resolve relative module imports within these “virtual” directories, as if they were merged in to one directory.

I would also remove the whole `"typeRoots"` field from your `tsconfig.json` : you should not need it anymore.

Note : I presume you also need `"allowJs": true`, or else the `tsc` compiler will not emit your `.js` files.

Comment: It doesn't work. I decided to read the documentation again :).